# Как удалить символ из строки?

Tags: javascript, php

На сайте есть поле для Telegram nickname, подразумевалось что люди будут вбивать туда свой ник в ТГ и выводится:

```
<a href="https://telegram.me/<?php echo $content_field->value; ?>"><?php echo $content_field->value; ?></a>
```

но некоторые пишут его с собачкой перед ником, в итоге ссылка с собачкой telegram.me/@nickname 
не работает

как вырезать этот символ из ссылки если он есть?

Answer (score 1):

Самый лучший способ - использовать функцию ltrim() вместо str_replace()

```
<a href="https://telegram.me/<?php echo ltrim($content_field->value, "@"); ?>"><?php echo $content_field->value; ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let nick = 'telegram.me/@nickname';

console.log(nick.replace('@', ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = '@nickname';
$out = str_replace('@','', $var);

var_dump($out); // string(8) "nickname"
```

Ваш пример:

```
<a href="https://telegram.me/<?php echo str_replace('@','', $content_field->value); ?>"><?php echo $content_field->value; ?></a>
```

Лучше это на стророне php делать чем на js